# WebAPI OData could not load microsoft.data.odata version=5.6.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget

When I construct Asp.Net WebAPI using VisualStudio 2013, adding

> Web API 2 OData Controller with actions using Entity FrameWork

[image]

after add successfully, I run the API, then the error occur：

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spend long time to try and seems find the solution：

**1. Open Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage Nuget  Packages For solution**

and serach the word "data" shows:

[image]

**2. As the error says** `Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0" Could not load`, you can find that there's  `Microsoft.Data.OData` installed here, name `OdataLib for OData v1-3`, but its version is 5.6.3 not 5.6.0.0

**3. Hence now manage it and uncheck all project to uninstall it,** but you'll meet the error `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0 depends on it`, hence you should first uninstalled `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0`

[image]

**4. Then Uninstall other three packages, their id are :**

.

```
Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.Data.Edm
System.Spatial
```

[image]

**5. reinstall** `Microsoft.Data.OData -Version 5.6.0`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.6.0

using Package Manager Console

> Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData -Version 5.6.0

then the three orange will be reinstall with ver 5.6.0.0

[image]

**6. reinstall** `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/5.0.0

using Package Manager Console

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Version 5.0.0

**7. Then I can run the API without error**